# Finding an intuitive understanding of $\operatorname e$ and natural logs...

Tags: exponential-function

http://betterexplained.com/articles/an-intuitive-guide-to-exponential-functions-e/

"this is wild! $e^x$ can mean two things:

x is the number of times we multiply a growth rate: 100% growth for 3 years is $e^3$
x is the growth rate itself: 300% growth for one year is $e^3$.
Won’t this overlap confuse things? Will our formulas break and the world come to an end?

It all works out. When we write:

the variable x is a combination of rate and time.

Let me explain. When dealing with continuous compound growth, 10 years of 3% growth has the same overall impact as 1 year of 30% growth (and no growth afterward).

10 years of 3% growth means 30 changes of 1%. These changes happen over 10 years, so you are growing continuously at 3% per year.
1 period of 30% growth means 30 changes of 1%, but happening in a single year. So you grow for 30% a year and stop."

I don't understand why 10 year of 3% growth means 30 changes of 1%. I don't understand why they are making this comparison here? I read this site but this is the part that i'm kind of hung up on?

Comment: any answers?????

Comment: In fact there are MANY definitions of $e$. Here are [five](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definitions_of_the_exponential_function).

Answer (score 1):

Let's back up a bit. Recall how [compound interest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_interest#Compound_Interest) works when there are $n$ compounding periods per year:

$$
A=P\left(1+{r\over n}\right)^{nt}.
$$

Now thinking of there being more and more and more compounding periods in a year (every month, every day, every hour, every minute, every second, etc.) so that we are taking the limit as $n\to\infty$ in the above expression. This is called *continuously compounded interest* and is related to a base $e$ exponential function via
$$
A=\lim_{n\to\infty}P\left(1+{r\over n}\right)^{nt}=P\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\left(1+{r\over n}\right)^{n}\right]^t=P[e^r]^t=Pe^{rt},
$$
where we have used one of the [definitions of $e$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definitions_of_the_exponential_function):
$$
e:=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+{1\over n}\right)^n \implies e^r=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+{r\over n}\right)^n \implies e^{rt}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+{r\over n}\right)^{nt}.
$$

So a key thing you're missing in your analysis is non-continuous compounding vs. continuous compounding which moves us from a base $1+{r\over n}$ exponential function to a base $e$ exponential function.

---

So take your example: $100\%$ growth ($r=1$), continuously compounded for $3$ years results in $A=Pe^{1\cdot 3}=Pe^3$, i.e., the new amount is $e^3$ times the starting principal $P$.

On the other hand, $10$ years of $3\%$ growth ($r=0.03$) compounded continuously results in $A=Pe^{0.03\cdot 10}=Pe^{0.3}$.

These two are *not* the same!

Comment: Let me think about this.

Answer (score 1):

Referring to your question, **""10 years of 3% growth means 30 changes of 1%  ""**

what is meant by above sentence is - final value = (e^3%)^10  = (e^1%)^30  = e^0.3 Clearly they are the same because they produce the same output.

**""1 period of 30% growth means 30 changes of 1%, but happening in a single year. So you grow for 30% a year and stop""**

what is meant by above sentence is - final value = (e^30%)^1 = e^0.3. Hence they are all the same in terms of producing the same final value i.e. e^0.3